# SQLlite strftime function to get grouped data by months

Tags: sql, sqlite

i have table with following structure and data:

[image]

I would like to get grouped data by months in given date range for example (from 2014-01-01 to 2014-12-31). Data for some months cannot be available but i still need to have in result information that in given month is result 0.

Result should have following format:

```
    MONTH   |    DIALS_CNT   | APPT_CNT | CONVERS_CNT | CANNOT_REACH_CNT | 
    2014-01 |    100         | 50       | 20          |  30              |
    2014-02 |    100         | 40       | 30          |  30              |
    2014-03 |      0         |  0       |  0          |   0              |
etc..
```

WHERE

```
    APPT_CNT = WHERE call.result = APPT
    CONVERS_CNT = WHERE call.result = CONV_NO_APPT
    CANNOT_REACH_CNT = WHERE call.result = CANNOT_REACH
```

How can i do it please with usage function **strftime** ?

Many thanks for any  help or example.

Comment: Really nobody knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Month,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE date LIKE Month || '%'
       ) AS Dials_Cnt,
       (SELECT SUM(Call_Result = 'APPT')
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE date LIKE Month || '%'
       ) AS Appt_Cnt,
       ...
FROM (SELECT '2014-01' AS Month UNION ALL
      SELECT '2014-02'          UNION ALL
      SELECT '2014-03'          UNION ALL
      ...
      SELECT '2014-12')
```