# get grouped data by conditions during date

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with the following structure:

[image]

I would like to create query which gives me result in following format for two date ranges:

```
    FROM       |   TO       |    DIALS_CNT   | APPT_CNT | CONVERS_CNT | CANNOT_REACH_CNT | 
    2014-09-30 |  2014-10-06|    100         | 50       | 20          |  30            |
```

```
    FROM = Date from given to between range
    TO = Date to given to between range
    APPT_CNT = WHERE call.result = APPT
    CONVERS_CNT = WHERE call.result = CONV_NO_APPT
    CANNOT_REACH_CNT = WHERE call.result = CANNOT_REACH
```

I tried to use inner select with count and WHERE conditions, but without luck:

```
SELECT 
  dc.date,
  (SELECT COUNT('APPT') FROM dialed_calls 
  WHERE dc.call_result = 'APPT') as APPT_CNT
FROM dialed_calls AS dc
GROUP BY dc.date  
WHERE dc.date BETWEEN '2014-09-30' AND '2014-10-06';
```

Comment: What query have you already tried?  What was the erroneous output?

Comment: you expect only one row of output?

Comment: There is no `call_result` column in the table shown.

Comment: You should put GROUP BY clause after WHERE clause in your code. And add date filter condition into the sub query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is really unclear. According to your code , I guess you have a call detail table with a call_result column and a date column in it.

If you want count different type of calls throught call_result, you could use sum instead of count like this:

```
SELECT '2014-09-30' as from,
       '2014-10-06' as to,
       COUNT(*) AS DIALS_CNT,   
       SUM(CASE WHEN dc.call_result = 'APPT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS APPT_CNT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN dc.call_result = 'CONV_NO_APPT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CONVERS_CNT ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN dc.call_result = 'CANNOT_REACH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CANNOT_REACH_CNT 
  FROM dialed_calls dc
 WHERE  dc.date BETWEEN '2014-09-30' AND '2014-10-06'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a `BETWEEN` statement to grab the appropriate date ranges and a `COUNT` aggregation to list your counts. [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_operators.htm) is a list of useful operators for SQLite and [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) is some detail on aggregations.

Just be careful to list your date ranges appropriately as shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187288/sql-select-between-dates), SQLite is picky about it's date formatting.

**----------------------------------EDIT-----------------------------------**

Try this query:

```
SELECT dc.date, COUNT('APPT')
FROM dialed_calls AS dc
WHERE dc.date BETWEEN '2014-09-30' AND '2014-10-06'
GROUP BY dc.date;
```

Comment: Hello, yes I used BETWEEN, but it returns a lot of lines. I need to return only one row with computed data for given date range as in example result.

Comment: You need to use COUNT and GROUP BY in order to aggregate something. I would recommend walking through some tutorials at w3schools for ANSI SQL syntax. Here is a good starting point for GROUP BY: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: @GeorgeSmith I took your query above and fixed the syntax issues... try the one listed above. To add additional counted columns, you can just add an additional COUNT(fieldname) for each field needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is like [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147496/sqllite-strftime-function-to-get-grouped-data-by-months), but with two columns and BETWEEN:

```
SELECT zFrom AS "FROM",
       zTo AS "TO",
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE date BETWEEN zFrom AND zTo
       ) AS Dials_Cnt,
       (SELECT SUM(Call_Result = 'APPT')
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE date BETWEEN zFrom AND zTo
       ) AS Appt_Cnt,
       ...
FROM (SELECT '2014-09-30' AS zFrom, '2014-10-06 9' AS zTo UNION ALL
      SELECT '2014-10-07',          '2014-10-13 9'        UNION ALL
      ...)
```

The additional `9` in the end dates ensures that the times match even for that date.